# Git Status - showing unpushed commits

Tags: git, github

`git status` command showing unpushed commits (as mentioned below), while I have already pushed these changes on remote branch and all changes are present in remote branch.

> On branch Projects/ABC
>   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Projects/ABC' by 3 commits.

Comment: Are you sure you really pushed to `origin` and not another remote?
Are you sure you really pushed to `Projects/ABC` and not another branch?
What does `git log --oneline Projects/ABC..origin/Projects/ABC` tell you?

Comment: @eckes , this command not giving any output.

Comment: ok. And the reverse? `git log --oneline origin/Projects/ABC..Projects/ABC`? If you receive this message, you clearly didn't push. At least not to `origin/Projects/ABC`

Comment: reverse is showing my all three commits.  The commits which are already present on remote branch. I think issue might be related to remote tracking. It is unable to track remote branch. I have started a new setup, so I think some setup is required to enable tracking for remote.

Comment: no. you **are** already tracking `origin/Projects/ABC`. If you wouldn't track it, you won't receive `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Projects/ABC' by 3 commits`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git tell you that you did not pushed your changes.

If you try to push but your branch is not up to date with the remote the push will fail.

Do this to verify that you have pushed the code:

```
# Update the local repo with the remote code
# If there will be line with the branch name it means that your local repo 
# was not up to date with the remote repo.
git fetch --all --prune

# update your local branch with the latest code
git pull origin Projects/ABC

# now you are fully up to date and you can push it
git push origin Projects/ABC
```

Comment: Is fetch necessary, if we are doing pull?

Comment: Not a mandatory but its better this way. Sine you pull origin/XXX its getting the data from the remote and not locally

Comment: but I am not sure why I should push again as I have already done it and changes there are present also.

Comment: Well, fetch did work and local branch is in sync with remote now, but I was hoping that branch status should update at the time of push to the remote..anyways now after fetch it is not showing unpushed commits. Thanks.